# Change collation of database in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, collation, database-administration

How do I change the collation name of all databases in Database to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS in MS-SQL ?

Also I need the new databases to follow this collation name.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the default collation for an instance of SQL Server can be a complex operation and involves the following steps:

1. **Make sure you have all the information or scripts** needed to re-create your user databases and all the objects in them.
2. Export all your data using a tool such as the [bcp Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). For
   more information, see [Importing and Exporting Bulk Data.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
3. **Drop all the user databases.**
4. Rebuild the master database specifying the new collation in the **SQLCOLLATION** property of the **setup** command. For example:

   Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=InstanceName 
   /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=accounts /[ SAPWD= StrongPassword ] 
   /SQLCOLLATION=CollationName

For more information, see [Rebuilding System Databases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).
Create all the databases and all the objects in them.
Import all your data.

The original source is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Please bold the part with "Drop all the user databases". And repeat it a thousand times :-). The OP needs to understand this is no small feat he's asking. There's no switch that just changes your server or db collation.